# Qt signal emission and QThread execution flow

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qobject

Here's a piece of the [Threads and QObjects doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) of Qt

> Direct Connection The slot is invoked immediately, when the signal is
>   emitted. The slot is executed in the emitter's thread, which is not
>   necessarily the receiver's thread.

So let's admit I am stuck in a

```
while (this->true_bool);
```

in thread 1, and thread2 emits a signal, connected to a slot of the "this" object of the above line, will it be executed after the loop exits (so never) or will it be executed immediately and after the slot returns, it get back to the while (so if i change this->true_bool to false it will end the loop)?

It seems weird to me that it would cause an immediat call of the slot but the docs seems to say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be executed immediately in the **thread2**, independent of the loop in the **thread1**.

> ...The slot is executed in the emitter's thread, which is not
>   necessarily the receiver's thread...

**EDIT:** I think this answer about QThread will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35056527/4149835

Answer (score 3):

Qt calls work as follows:

- Direct connection. Whenever you have a direct connection then the emit call does the following: enumerate all the connected slots and call them one-by-one. Slots are functions and they gets called immediately during the emit call. So, once `emit Something()` completes, all the slots directly connected to it were executed. Think of it as an array of function pointers which get executed one by one during the call. So all the slots are executed on the same thread that you call the signal.
- Queued connection. It is similar to the direct connection but instead of calling each slot directly it posts it to the queue of the object which is associated with each slot. Hence, the slot gets executed by the event loop with which the target object associated. And so it gets executed by the thread the target object is living in not the one the signal was called on(in case the threads for the target object and the signal call are not the same). So when the signal call completes it means that for all the queued connections `QEvents` were posted to the appropriate queues but it doesn't mean the slots were executed yet.