# How do I start polling with mutex locked thread in QT?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, polling

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Qt version 4.8.3.
In Qt main window I manage to open my devices and this part of the code is working.
Now after I open devices I need to wait if a card is present. It means I have to use polling to get the data from card. But the polling must be infinite loop. Polling for card arrival and removal.

Example poll for card arrival every 20ms and when a card is detected I need to switch poll for card removal every 20 ms. So when a card arrival or removal is detected, my app signals Qt event such that another Qt thread can now proceed to read/write the card.

I read about QThread, mutex locked so on and I am bit confused.
I have a main window plus a worker class. In my mainwindow I code as;

```
// Open a reader (from my SDK)
cReader.open 

//If the reader is open use;

thread = new QThread();
worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(worker,SIGNAL(??????),SLOT(?????);
connect(worker,SIGNAL(?????),SLOT(?????);
.........
```

First I must use connect for SIGNAL/SLOT and start the card arrival/removal polling. Than if any card detected I have signal to another thread to read from card or write into the card.

So I don’t know where to start or how to call signal/slot? I need help to fill the ?????? above SIGNAL/SLOT.

**Edited:** I also need mutex lock shared by the polling thread and the card handiling thread. This is because a card poll command will invalidate my mifare session if opened.

Any help please,
Kind Regards,

Comment: On a side note, `QT` is for QuickTime. `Qt` is the framework you are talking about.

Comment: If you are just polling, you don't really *need* another thread. It might be useful to have one (if you need very exact 20 ms, or if polling call actually takes many milliseconds), but your should write your code so that it also works single threaded. So just use a repeating `QTimer` with 20 ms interval, and which each timer signal, do your polling, compare result to previous poll result, and emit signal if there was a change.

Comment: As to how to use Qt signals and slots, you should really just plain learn the basics: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html for to-the-point introduction, something like http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html for practical example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not thread-safe (unless one `QObject` accesses data in another `QObject` and both belong to the same thread).

In terms of usage of mutexes the `QMutexLocker` is your friend and I advise you to use it instead of manually handling the locking/unlocking.

If you re-read your question you will notice that you heavily use intervals. And how do we handle intervals? Using `QTimer`. Here is my suggestion:

- Create a `QTimer` along with the worker `QObject`
- Set the interval of the timer to 20ms or whatever interval you want for it to tigger an event; a timer with interval set to 0 means that an event will be triggered by it as soon as possible
- Connect the timer to the slot of the worker that does the work (check if card is removed etc.)
- Connect the object's slots/signals to the signals/slots of your UI (using `QMutexLocker` will enable you to secure the access on the internal data of both) or another `QObject` (in the same or a different thread where the worker is residing)
- Move both the timer and worker to a `QThread` and start the thread

The timer will start triggering a check for your card every X milliseconds. The worker will then receive that signal from the timer (here no mutex is required since both the timer and the worker are with the same thread-affinity). Things will change internally for the worker and then it will emit a signal to another `QObject` or the UI itself. At this point the mutexes come into play unless you are accessing another instance of a `QObject` in the same thread where your worker is.

You can add as many threads as you like by doing so. I have a UI that has 6 threads running in the background accessing both the UI and each other without any problem using timers.

**EDIT:** 
I have started working on a [small demo](https://gitlab.com/aleksandaratanasov/qt_qthread_qobject_demo/tree/master) using `QTimer`, `QThread` and `QObject`. Application is incomplete/buggy but you can see how `QTimer` works.

Comment: My problem I dont know how to and where to create a QTimer. Also after I oveToThread how to code using connect(signal/slot).

Comment: I understand your suggestion and found many examples. My problem that I cannot get it (my brain stuck because of this is first time for me). Can you show me an example as what you said on your post?

Comment: I've started working on a small widget a couple of days ago to research the `QObject`/`QThread` combo (before that I was using the very old now convention of subclassing `QThread`). I have edited my post to include a link to it. Mind that it's still work in progress (especially in the mutex departement :D) but it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`QMutex`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutex.html) for protection an object, on the example of your cReader:

```
// class member
QMutex m_mutex;
//...

QByteArray MyClass::safeReadSomeData()
{
    m_mutex.lock();
    QByteArray result = cReader.read();
    m_mutex.unlock();

    return result;    
}
```

See also [QMutexLocker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html), [QReadWriteLock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qreadwritelock.html).

Common and usual way for communication and parameters exchange between threads is using [signals & slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). Example:

```
thread = new QThread();
worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect( thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(startMyWork()) );
connect( worker, SIGNAL(sigCardDetected()), someOtherObject, SLOT(onCardDetected()) );
thread->start();
//...
```

Useful article from official documentation: [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html)

Also I think this answer about **`QThread`** will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35056527/4149835

p.s. Are you sure that you need to use two different additional threads for detecting and reading/writing?

Comment: Incorrect. Please read: `QObject and all of its subclasses are not thread-safe`. You still need to protect the shared data. Further (again quoting the link you gave yourself): `If you are calling a function on an QObject subclass that doesn't live in the current thread and the object might receive events, you must protect all access to your QObject subclass's internal data with a mutex; otherwise, you may experience crashes or other undesired behavior.`

Comment: @rbaleksandar, It is correct if author not going to use the same objects in different threads. And, I think he does not need to use shared data.

Comment: Specifying connection type is generally a bad idea. I've read many times that in 99% of the cases if you need to define connection type you are doing something wrong. As for the read/write and the detection not being in the same thread it makes perfect sense especially if the detection influences other operations. If you combine both than the detection process will be blocked until the read/write is finished.

Comment: @rbaleksandar, But who told about specifying connection type? He doesn't need to specify connection type, because for different threads `Qt::AutoConnection` is equal to `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Comment: Why mention it in your answer? :) You should rewrite that you have quoted in your case since it introduces unnecessary new terminology => less understanding by the reader.

Comment: @Vladimir, I edit my question. To write into the card I need to read first. I need to read card info, load key, authenticate and than do some staff before writing into the card. rbaleksandar suggesiton looks good to me. But can any one make a small example from it, so I can get it. Having difficulty to put in the code.

Comment: @NTMS, ok. Even if you need to use some shared data and mutex locking, please note that using signals and slots are common & usual way for communication and parameters exchange between threads. You can see an example of signals/slots connection in my answer.

Comment: @Vladimir, Thank you. Is it possible to edit your code based on rbaleksandar suggestion below, so I can start coding. And if any error arrives I will open another questions. Kind thanks.