# how to pass pointer to a Subclassed Qthread,in Multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I create some class like this:

```
class TcpClient: public QObject
{
    public TcpClient(){}
    QSocket *socket;

    QMutex mutex;

    void write()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        socket->write();
    }
}

class SubQthread :public QThread
{
    public:
    SubQthread(TcpClient *tcp)
    {
        //
        m_tcp = tcp;

    }
    private:
    TcpClient *m_tcp;
    protected:
    void run()
    {
        m_tcp->write();
    }

}


class Widget:public QWidget
{
    public:
    Widget()
    {
        client =  new TcpClient(this);


    }
    private:
    TcpClient *client;


}
```

When I create multiple sub-QThreads, I pass the pointer TcpClient* to QThread. Is this a good idea?
On the condition that i can ensure TcpClient* will be deleted after the app finished.

Comment: Having multiple threads communicating through the same socket is generally a bad idea, even with locking. What is your use-case? Why do all the threads need to use the same socket? Can't you have one socket and one connection *per thread*?

Comment: I think this belongs to Code Review

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your codes that should be addressed.

- There is no `QSocket` class in Qt framework. I presume you are using `QTcpSocket`.
- `QTcpSocket`s cannot be used across multiple threads. Only their creating threads can call their methods.
- The mutex object should be shared across all threads.

If you want to implement a communication channel between multiple threads, suggestions are:

- [QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html).
- Signal/slot for small amount of data.
- Manually implementing shared variables protected by mutexes.
- Event loops.

Answer (score 0):

1. `QTcpSocket` object (and each other object of `QObject` derived class) lives in a thread where it was created. If you create `QTcpSocket` object in main (GUI) thread and want that it lives in another thread, you should use `QObject::moveToThread` method: [qt thread with movetothread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033971/qt-thread-with-movetothread). But the right way is create socket just in working thread or use creating in necessary thread by using socket descriptor: [`QAbstractSocket::setSocketDescriptor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketDescriptor)
2. You should be sure that you call your `QTcpSocket` object from the same thread that it lives. For this purpose you can use Signals & Slots with [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Comment: thank you very much! I have understood your meaning,meanwhile,thanks  for bearing my bad English

Comment: @M.Joe, See also: [what is the correct way to implement a `QThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093159/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-qthread-example-please) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35056527/4149835